# Find a monotone subsequence converging to limsup

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

This is not a duplicate. Please read carefully.

First, I know every sequence has a monotone subsequence. [For an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/716513/549321).

Second, I know we can construct a subsequence converging to limsup. [For an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/912768/549321).

The question is: can we construct a monotone subsequence converging to limsup?
The reason I asked this is that from the following exercises

[image]
[image]

My answer to 27 is the following:

> For $\epsilon = 1$, we have $a_n< M + 1$ for all but finitely many
> $n$. Pick out these finite $n$'s, and denote the largest number of these $n$'s as $N_1$, and $M - 1 < a_n$ for infinitely many $n$, choose $n_1$ which satisfies $n_1>N_1$
> (we can because Archimedean property).
>
> For $\epsilon = 1/2$, we have $a_n< M + 1/2$ for all but finitely many
> $n$. Pick out these finite $n$'s, and denote the largest number of these $n$'s as $N_2$, and $M - 1/2 < a_n$ for infinitely many $n$, choose $n_2$ which satisfies
> $n_2>max\{N_1,n_1\}$ (we can because Archimedean property). Continuing
> we get $\{a_{n_k}\}$ as the subsequence. QED

The author seems to encourage me to imitate the argument in 27 to prove 28.

So I guess he implies that there is a monotone subsequence converging to limsup.
But how?

Comment: If as you say $a_n<M+1$ for *all but finitely many $n$* then there is no largest such $n.$ Therefore you cannot as you do denote "the largest of these $n$" as $N_1.$ [namely because there is no largest.]

Comment: @coffeemath,  thank you, this mistake has been corrected now.

Comment: When you say 'Pick out these finite $n$'s', you assume that there is at least $1$ for which $a_n \geq M + 1$. It could be the case that no such $n$ exists.

Comment: I see no such implication in Ex. 28. The goal is only to find a monotone subsequence, and the author suggests that the proof is similar (which you already know is true).

Comment: You've shown you are capable of writing in math jax.  So please stop posting images of questions.  Links and images die .... Since you know very well how to format, I take it you post images when you feel too lazy to put the effort into formatting?

Comment: @Not just lazy, because my time is limited sometimes. However, I know now it is a very irresponsible way of doing things to this community. It won't happen in my future posts. Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By combining your two stated facts, you can answer the question. Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence. Then some subsequence, say $(a_{n_j})_{j=1}^\infty$, converges to $\lim\sup a_n$ by your second statement. For ease of notation, set $b_j = a_{n_j}$. Then by your first statement, we know that the sequence $(b_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ has a monotone subsequence, say $(b_{j_k})_{k=1}^\infty$. The monotone subsequence $(b_{j_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, so we're done.

Comment: This is what I thought, too. Thank you